# Add traceId in sleuth from request header

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, opentracing

I want to use spring cloud sleuth in my application. For each request I am getting "traceId" in the header and I want sleuth to use this as trace id. But the issue is sleuth is taking trace id from header only when the key is "X-B3-TraceId".
So to change this I am using [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#how-to-change-context-propagation). But when I try to build the application, I am getting this:

```
SpringBootKafkaTestApplicationTests > contextLoads() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at ConstructorResolver.java:658
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException at SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185
                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at HexCodec.java:26
```

On starting the server I am getting this:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
 2021-06-20 21:56:17.541 ERROR             [,,${false}] ---- Application run failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaTracing' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/brave/instrument/messaging/BraveMessagingAutoConfiguration$SleuthKafkaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [brave.kafka.clients.KafkaTracing]: Factory method 'kafkaTracing' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.test.kafka.springbootkafkatest.SpringBootKafkaTestApplication.main(SpringBootKafkaTestApplication.java:13) [main/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [brave.kafka.clients.KafkaTracing]: Factory method 'kafkaTracing' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at brave.internal.codec.HexCodec.lowerHexToUnsignedLong(HexCodec.java:26) ~[brave-5.13.2.jar:?]
    at com.test.kafka.springbootkafkatest.Utils.CustomPropagator.lambda$extractor$1(CustomPropagator.java:32) ~[main/:?]
    at brave.kafka.clients.KafkaTracing.<init>(KafkaTracing.java:170) ~[brave-instrumentation-kafka-clients-5.13.2.jar:?]
    at brave.kafka.clients.KafkaTracing$Builder.build(KafkaTracing.java:133) ~[brave-instrumentation-kafka-clients-5.13.2.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.brave.instrument.messaging.BraveMessagingAutoConfiguration$SleuthKafkaConfiguration.kafkaTracing(BraveMessagingAutoConfiguration.java:124) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-autoconfigure-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    ... 24 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am using Spring boot version - '2.5.0' and spring cloud version - '2020.0.3'
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why have you cropped full stack trace? Also you have not mentioned that this happens in your test. I have no idea how your test setup looks like

Comment: I have commented the test now. I have added the error that I am getting on starting the server.

Answer (score -1):

Before asking a question please always read the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#how-to-change-context-propagation

I'm copying the code from the docs for your convenience

```
@Component
  class CustomPropagator extends Propagation.Factory implements Propagation<String> {

    @Override
    public List<String> keys() {
        return Arrays.asList("myCustomTraceId", "myCustomSpanId");
    }

    @Override
    public <R> TraceContext.Injector<R> injector(Setter<R, String> setter) {
        return (traceContext, request) -> {
            setter.put(request, "myCustomTraceId", traceContext.traceIdString());
            setter.put(request, "myCustomSpanId", traceContext.spanIdString());
        };
    }

    @Override
    public <R> TraceContext.Extractor<R> extractor(Getter<R, String> getter) {
        return request -> TraceContextOrSamplingFlags.create(TraceContext.newBuilder()
                .traceId(HexCodec.lowerHexToUnsignedLong(getter.get(request, "myCustomTraceId")))
                .spanId(HexCodec.lowerHexToUnsignedLong(getter.get(request, "myCustomSpanId"))).build());
    }

    @Override
    public <K> Propagation<K> create(KeyFactory<K> keyFactory) {
        return StringPropagationAdapter.create(this, keyFactory);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have read the docs and i used the same code but I am getting `NullPointerException` for `KafkaTracing` bean while running the server and its pointing to `lowerHexToUnsignedLong(getter.get(request, "traceId"))` this line.

Comment: So your question is completely not related to the actual issue you're having. Can you update the question and show the stack trace? Also Show which version you're using of sleuth, boot and cloud?